# Error during indexing with Apache Solr: multiple values encountered for non multiValued field keywords

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to quickly index a large collection of html files for a once off information retrieval experiment with Apache Lucene Solr. I'm using the example Solr instance distributed with the latest release (`solr-4.9.0/example/solr`) and in the spirit of a quick and dirty solution I'm just submitting the documents with curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=001 -F myfile=@blah.html
```

When I look at the logs in the Solr panel during indexing I see a lot of errors of the form:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=BLOG06-20060103-014-0011844415] multiple values encountered for non multiValued field keywords: [hair care,​ shampoo,​ hair styles,​ hair styles,​ ...]
```

It looks like the component doing the keyword extraction is pulling out multiple values when  perhaps it should only be a list of words separated by whitespace. Do I need to do anything to force this, or does this look like some kind of bug?

Comment: Have a look in the schema.xml and check if the field keywords is defined as `multiValued="true"` or not.

Comment: Ah yes that fixed the problem. I feel a little silly now. I guess I was assuming that the default schema provided for the example installation would have been setup match the default document parser config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the solution was as simple as ensuring that the keywords field in `schema.xml` has `multiValued="true"` specified. I then had to do this for a couple of other fields. I had foolishly assumed that the schema would be set up to match the default document parser in the demo instance.